# Ruby syntax vs PHP class constructor syntax?

Tags: php, ruby, constructor

In Ruby, I wouldn't define variables prior to the constructor. Tutorials in PHP suggest that I do, though it seems to work when I don't.

What benefit does this approach provide? Is there a difference between the Ruby function `initialize` and the PHP function `__construct`?

```
class ConnectToDatabase {

  public $host;
  public $user;
  public $password;
  public $database;

  function __construct($host, $user, $password, $database) {
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->database = $database;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ruby doesn't have function `initialise`.

Comment: But Class#allocate has a block with initialize http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Class.html#method-i-allocate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general defining the classes member variables outside of the member functions provides a few benefits.

They clearly indicate what is **intended** to be a member variable. This is not to be underestimated. Other developers, and even yourself in 5 months, will want to know what are the member variables. If one has to hunt through the member functions of the class, one may miss a variable. In any case, it would take longer to find.

Also, any code completion your *IDE* will be using, will probably **not** be able to pick up the member variables if they are **only** declared in the constructor.

Finally, you can *override* the constructor. In that case, those member variables may **not** be available.

FROM @meager: An important one; "You can change them from public to private, and you can initialize them with static values."

Answer (score 3):

> What benefit does this approach provide?

You can change them from `public` to `private`, and you can initialize them with static values.

> Is there a difference between the ruby function initialise and the php function __construct?

Yes, they are very different. They aren't really comparable; Ruby and PHP's object model is too different.